# How to convert numbers in txt file into coordinate form?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

```
import java.io.*;
public class Point
{
private double x;
private double y;
public Point(double x_coord, double y_coord)
{
    x = x_coord;
    y = y_coord;
}
}
public class PointArray
{

private Point points[];
public PointArray ( FileInputStream fileIn) throws IOException
{
    try
    {
        BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(fileIn));
        int numberOfPoints = Integer.parseInt(inputStream.readLine());
        points = new Point[numberOfPoints];
        int i=0;
        String line;
        while ((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.print(line);
            double x = Double.parseDouble(line.split(" ")[0]);
            double y = Double.parseDouble(line.split(" ")[1]);
            points[i] = new Point (x, y);
            i++;
        }
    inputStream.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
}
public String toString()
{
    String format = "{";
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++)
    {
        if (i < points.length-1)
        format = format + points[i] + ", ";
        else
        format = format + points[i];
    }
    format = format + "}";
    return format;
}
public static void main(String[]args)
{
FileInputStream five = new FileInputStream(new File("fivePoints.txt"));
PointArray fivePoints =  new PointArray (five);
System.out.println(fivePoints.toString());
}
```

The txt file fivePoints is as shown below:

```
5
2 7
3 5
11 17
23 19
150 1
```

The number in the first line is the number of points.

My problem:
When I compile the program, everything is good. However, when I call the main method, I can only print them out like 2 73 511 1723 19150 1 4000 30000. I want to convert 5 different points into coordinate form by using toString(). How can I fix it?

Comment: You should probably start by overriding `toString` in the class `Point`.

Comment: Start by changing `System.out.print(line);` to `System.out.println(line);`

Comment: I don't know where are 4000 and 30000 from.

Answer (score 0):

You need some modifications in your code to be able to print the points like below, if I understand correct that is your requirement:

```
{(2.0, 7.0)(3.0, 5.0)(11.0, 17.0)(23.0, 19.0)(150.0, 1.0)}
```

In order to achieve the above output by invoking `toString()`, you need to do the following:

1) Override the `toString()` method in the `Point` class as shown below (That is where you format single Point object):

```
public String toString() {
        return "(" + x + ", " + y + ")";
    }
```

2) You need to modify the `overrided toString()` method in `PointArray` class to as follow (This is where you formatted array of formatted Point objects):

```
public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
        sb.append("{"); 
        for(int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            sb.append(points[i].toString());
        }
        sb.append("}");
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

With above two you should be able to get the output shown above.

As commented by @MadProgrammer, remove the `System.out.print(line);` from the beginning of your while loop because it will confuse you.

Comment: I want the format like this {(2.0, 7.0), (3.0, 5.0), (11.0,17.0), (23.0, 19.0), (150.0, 1.0)}.

Comment: @Chriseagles updated the answer, see that I have changed the toString() of Point class to include rounded brackets and that would add rounded racket to each point. Then I updated the toString() method of PointArray to inculde opening and closing curly brackets. If the answer helped you, then you can mark it as **accepted**